# Routing Order / Signing Group information in the connect response?

Tags: docusignapi

I´m trying to understand the response the connect API (using the webhook status updates) sends. The documentation says, the answer only provides XML elements of EvenvelopeStatus type (plus document PDFs, if requested). This does not include current routing order information or signing group information, right?

1. Does anyone know, if this is true and if there is a workaround, how to get the current routing order within the connect message without parsing the recipients status?
2. If one of the recipients is a signing group, will the name and email field remain empty until one of the group members has viewed / signed the document? Then I would expect the name / email field to be filled with the actual signer.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current routing situation can be determined from the notification message. See the status attributes for the envelope's recipients.

You need to infer the current routing status by looking at the `status` values for the recipients. Here is an example notification. You can see that one of the recipients is in `completed` status and the other is in `sent` status.

Remember that multiple recipients can be in `sent` status at the same time if the envelope is using parallel routing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
<EnvelopeStatus>
    <RecipientStatuses>
        <RecipientStatus>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <Email>Sam.Spade@example.com</Email>
            <UserName>Sam Spade</UserName>
            <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
            <Sent>2019-05-07T10:43:40.073</Sent>
            <Delivered>2019-05-07T10:44:06.023</Delivered>
            <Signed>2019-05-07T10:44:12.323</Signed>
            <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Status>Completed</Status>
            <RecipientIPAddress>141.226.10.195</RecipientIPAddress>
            <CustomFields/>
            <TabStatuses>
                <TabStatus>
                    <TabType>SignHere</TabType>
                    <Status>Signed</Status>
                    <XPosition>341</XPosition>
                    <YPosition>697</YPosition>
                    <TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel>
                    <TabName>SignHere</TabName>
                    <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                </TabStatus>
                <TabStatus>
                    <TabType>SignHere</TabType>
                    <Status>Signed</Status>
                    <XPosition>416</XPosition>
                    <YPosition>412</YPosition>
                    <TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel>
                    <TabName>SignHere</TabName>
                    <DocumentID>2</DocumentID>
                    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                </TabStatus>
                <TabStatus>
                    <TabType>SignHere</TabType>
                    <Status>Signed</Status>
                    <XPosition>416</XPosition>
                    <YPosition>316</YPosition>
                    <TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel>
                    <TabName>SignHere</TabName>
                    <DocumentID>3</DocumentID>
                    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                </TabStatus>
            </TabStatuses>
            <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
            <RecipientId>64d1f093-d51e-4d38-914e-3255f46c0e18</RecipientId>
        </RecipientStatus>
        <RecipientStatus>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <Email>Susan.smith@example.com</Email>
            <UserName>Susan Smith</UserName>
            <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
            <Sent>2019-05-07T10:44:13.76</Sent>
            <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Status>Sent</Status>
            <RecipientIPAddress/>
            <CustomFields/>
            <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
            <RecipientId>ad82fdb5-dfe9-479e-a4ca-0032a51b076a</RecipientId>
        </RecipientStatus>
    </RecipientStatuses>
    <TimeGenerated>2019-05-07T10:47:56.4026603</TimeGenerated>
    <EnvelopeID>a65c99da-39aa-488f-909a-1b3964634758</EnvelopeID>
    <Subject>Please sign this document set</Subject>
    <UserName>Sam Spade</UserName>
    <Email>Sam.Spade@example.com</Email>
    <Status>Sent</Status>
    <Created>2019-05-07T10:43:27.943</Created>
    <Sent>2019-05-07T10:44:13.79</Sent>
    <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
    <ACStatusDate>2019-05-07T10:43:27.943</ACStatusDate>
    <ACHolder>Sam Spade</ACHolder>
    <ACHolderEmail>Sam.Spade@example.com</ACHolderEmail>
    <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
    <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
    <SenderIPAddress>141.226.10.195 </SenderIPAddress>
    <EnvelopePDFHash/>
    <CustomFields>
        <CustomField>
            <Name>Order ID</Name>
            <Show>True</Show>
            <Required>False</Required>
            <Value/>
        </CustomField>
        <CustomField>
            <Name>Sales order</Name>
            <Show>True</Show>
            <Required>False</Required>
            <Value>16</Value>
        </CustomField>
        <CustomField>
            <Name>AccountId</Name>
            <Show>false</Show>
            <Required>false</Required>
            <Value>3964103</Value>
            <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
        </CustomField>
        <CustomField>
            <Name>AccountName</Name>
            <Show>false</Show>
            <Required>false</Required>
            <Value>World Wide Corp</Value>
            <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
        </CustomField>
        <CustomField>
            <Name>AccountSite</Name>
            <Show>false</Show>
            <Required>false</Required>
            <Value>demo</Value>
            <CustomFieldType>Text</CustomFieldType>
        </CustomField>
    </CustomFields>
    <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
    <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
    <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
    <DocumentStatuses>
        <DocumentStatus>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>Order acknowledgement</Name>
            <TemplateName/>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
        </DocumentStatus>
        <DocumentStatus>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <Name>Battle Plan</Name>
            <TemplateName/>
            <Sequence>2</Sequence>
        </DocumentStatus>
        <DocumentStatus>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <Name>Lorem Ipsum</Name>
            <TemplateName/>
            <Sequence>3</Sequence>
        </DocumentStatus>
    </DocumentStatuses>
</EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

Comment: This was exactly the first question: is it possible to see the routing situation directly? Or do I have to interpret the recipients status?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers to my questions by debugging the interface. It is like expected: names of signing groups are reported in the name tag and replaced by the actual signers name after signing has been completed. Routing status has to be "calculated" by interpreting the recipients status - no overall routing info like in the envelope:get service call.

Comment: correct. I have now updated my answer to include an example of a notification message. Note that you can also call the Envelopes:get API method from your Connect listener.